# How to rotate a shape around a central axis

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-view

I'm surprised to find so few examples when it comes to Android animation. I have found the animation demos but they provide only a small set of what you might want to achieve.

For my particular case I'm just trying to animate a shape around a central point. I can see from the demo that you can use the following to pass in values:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofObject(
      ballHolder
    , "name"
    , new XYEvaluator()
    , position1, position2, position3, position4, positionEtc);
```

But how can I pass in all the values for a circle? I'm sure you wouldn't achieve it this way (as in, the example above).

Maybe I should be doing it a different way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this code and adjust it as you need :

To implement the rotation animation, you can define that animation in XML:
create an animation xml file under /res/anim folder called :rotate_around_center_point.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false"> 
   <rotate android:toDegrees="360"  
     android:duration="700"  
     android:pivotX="205"    
     android:pivotY="180"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
  </set>
```

apply the animation to View : lets say it for rotate image :

```
     ImageView animationTarget = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
     Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
     R.anim.rotate_around_center_point); animationTarget.startAnimation(animation);
```

OR

create the animation dynamically in Java code:

```
 Animation newAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, 205, 180);
 newAnimation.setDuration(700);
 animationTarget.startAnimation(newAnimation);
```

HOPE THIS HELP .